# Watching photos from photos library and swipe

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am using the below code to see the Movies in the photo library. Of course i get those Movies as a grid of photos.

```
-(BOOL)startMediaBrowserFromViewController:(UIViewController*)controller usingDelegate:(id )delegate {
    if (([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum] == NO)
        || (delegate == nil)
        || (controller == nil)) {
        return NO;
    }
    UIImagePickerController *mediaUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    mediaUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    mediaUI.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];
    mediaUI.allowsEditing = YES;
    mediaUI.delegate = delegate;
    [controller presentViewController:mediaUI animated:YES completion:nil];
    return YES;
}
```

Once i click one of them, i see the movie in full resolution and i have the ability play the movie or edit it. But i cannot swipe to see the movies to the left or right of the specific movie i selected.

Does someone know how to do it (if it's even possible)?

Let me know if you need anymore data.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using [ALAssetsLibrary](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) you can create your own custom interface that allows the user to interact in any way you want.

(I don't think you can tailor UIImagePickerController in the way you describe).

Comment: That's a major bummer. I have something i've made to watch it the way i want (using ALAssetsLibrary) but it doesn't look/feel exactly like i want. And also it doesn't have the ability to edit the movie or delete it cause they don't give delete privileges if not in regular photo library...